# Converting .avi to mov using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.avi output.mov
```

The above command works but

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -c:a output.mov
```

fails. But I'm jot able to figure out why

Answer (score 1):

On the second command, the option `-c:a` needs a value (an audio codec). Making the first command with explicit codec specification, it should read:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mov
```

as the default video codec is `libx264` and the default audio codec is `aac`. Replace these codecs to whatever you want to use.